# App starts normally But crashes when I click Button "oneplus"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

First of all let me tell you that I am a beginner at this... I started to try developing apps about a week ago.
When I start my app on a real device it starts normally But when I click the button "oneplus" it says that app isn't responding...
this app adds one number to the number in TextView .Earlier I faced same problem and thought it was because of fragments.So i removed them and made a very simple app But still the problem persists

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text=" + 1 "
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/plusone"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.tjain.oneup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements     View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num);
        int original = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
        int newnum = original + 1;
        number.setText(newnum);
    }
}
```

I am facing this error in other apps too. Maybe I am repeating my mistake . Please point it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your `LogCat` stack trace. Although I suspect it might be a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 1):

As I doubt for two scenario in your `onClick` for Exception

1. NumberFormat Exception
2. ResourceNotFound Exception

For First,

```
try
{
 int original = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception ex)
{
 ex.printStacktrace();
}
```

For Second,

Because int is not a argument for TextView's `setText` (only if its not a part of String resource id), as it will find with resource id not accepting as String value. and obvious Resource Not Found exception

you have to convert `int` to `String`,

```
 number.setText(String.valueOf(newnum));
```

Comment: It was a comment to support your case :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is adding your UI elements at the class level of your activity so you have one TextView object and one Button object, that way you only have to search for the resource once and you can add a click listener to the button itself like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private TextView mNumberTextView;
    private Button mOnePlusButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNumberTextView = findViewbyId(R.id.num);
        mOnePlusButton = findViewbyId(R.id.plusone);

        mOnePlusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                int original = Integer.parseInt(mNumberTextView.getText().toString());
                mNumberTextView.setText(original + 1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: Since you're still new at this, it's always a good idea to check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
number.setText(+newnum);
```

instead

```
number.setText(newnum);
```

Comment: Not works. Because for append string using overloading operator you have to define String like `""+newnum`.